# 3D chess Using adobe flash cs5 and OpenGL on android project possible?

Tags: android, opengl-es, adobe, flash-cs5, 3d

Can I Use both Adobe Flash cs5 and OpenGL to create an application on an android OS4.3 device?

I am creating a 3D chess game compatible for an android OS 4.3, so I am using eclipse and the SDK obviously.

The problem I have now is I am meant to make the chess pieces human like. For instance, the pawn pieces should look like miniature foot soldiers and the king piece should be a figure of a person sitting on a throne etc. I started with OpenGL but because I am new to it, I might not be able to carry put displaying the graphics with OpenGL. So I decided to use adobe flash cs5 to create the pieces and use OpenGL to make the chess board because I can do that and also because in my specs, I said I would be using OpenGL.

I want to know if this will actually work and also if there is a much easier way of doing this I just haven't thought of. Any suggestions would be appreciated, especially how to implement this with the A.I.

If anyone has a sample or an idea I could work with, I will also be very grateful.

Comment: Why not just use openGL? It seems like using flash as well is just adding more work.

Comment: I have updated my question now. I explain my problem in detail. Please help me.

Comment: Sounds like you're biting of far more than you can chew. Stick to either Flash or OpenGL and forget about the AI for now. I would say that should still be enough of a challenge for you.

Answer (score 1):

Adobe has said that "Stage 3D" support will be coming to mobile devices in the future, but in the meantime, there are not any ways to accelerate 3D with Adobe AIR.

Although Away3D or another 2.5D library would be fast enough for the web or desktop, I am not sure how well this will work for mobile, as AIR moves slow enough even for 2D games.

Since chess is a relatively static game, you might be able to create 3D graphics, then render to 2D sprites. I was the lead engineer for a large Facebook game, and we used this approach. ALthough it required more file size, it worked very well for quality and performance. The end result was something similar to Diablo 1, but in a cowboy theme instead of medieval.

Although it does not have true 3D support, yet, you might also consider looking into NME. That Facebook game I made ran at 5-6 FPS using Flash, but topped 30 FPS using NME on my old Palm Pre (so not the fastest phone in the world). That might help give you extra overhead to be able to lean into rich graphics. The framework will also publish as a true C++ NDK application, so it is actually possible to extend or modify the framework (it's open source) with your own OpenGL calls.

Here's the website if you're interested: http://www.haxenme.org